# Sorting based on columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

How to sort a matrix based on columns and its values in R?

For Example :
I have a matrix like this :

```
ID  Name    Number
1   Bat     43
2   Apple   42
4   Dog     41
5   Ball    41
6   Cat     40
```

I want to sort the matrix based on the values of the column `Number`. If two values are same then it should sort based on the column `Name`. The exepcted output should be

```
ID  Name    Number
6   Cat     40
5   Ball    41
4   Dog     41
2   Apple   42
1   Bat     43
```

Since, Ball and Dog has same value for the column `Number` . They are sorted according to the column `Name`(that is alphabetically). Can someone help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `order`:

```
df[with(df, order(Number, Name)), ]
```